# want to convert RSS to html using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rss

Sir i have a problem with my page i want to change the RSS to html using javascript . for this i was use feed2js from google code but whole was written in php and javascript . In my problem i want to make integration with JSP not only php please suggest me

Comment: What exactly does JavaScript have to do with JSP?

Comment: http://www.rss2html.com/ try this.

Answer (score 0):

XML is not the easiest format to work with in JavaScript, much easier if you can get a JSON feed of something, but as its an RSS feed you probably haven't got that choice.

You can parse XML in jQuery using http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jFeed